# How does DRF determine the title to show in the browseable API?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am creating many views with

```
ListAPIView.as_view(
    queryset=queryset,
    serializer_class=serializer_class
)
```

The DRF browseable API shows

[image]

In another project I work on, DRF renders the name of the model class. But that project subclasses `ViewSet`. Does the browseable API derive the title from the `ViewSet` or model class in some way? How can I override it with `ListAPIView.as_view()`?

Comment: Are you looking for https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/903204cd7926e9e6ceaaec1bfbf1ba3ed3330ca4/rest_framework/views.py#L24 ?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Yes, it looks like that is where the magic happens, assuming it is used in a template or something that renders the HTML for the browseable API page. I don't see an obvious way to override the name with `ListAPIView.as_view()`, though. I tried passing a kwarg called `name`, but `ListAPIView` doesn't have a `name` attribute so this throws an error.

Comment: May be define a subclass of `ListAPIView` that accepts `name` argument and sets it on the instance, that attribute should be picked by `get_view_name` then. Roughly something like this: https://ideone.com/kyXje7

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Or even just `class NamedApiView(ListApiView): name=None` will probably work.

Comment: Not really sure about that, I mean the `name = None` bit.  DRF will probably display `Named Api` in this case as the name using the class's name(`view.__class__.__name__`), but this will require defining a different subclass for every new name.